# React Native throws Access denied Error while building

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting in this error in console.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task
>   ':react-native-linear-gradient:processDebugManifest' property
>   'aaptFriendlyManifestOutputDirectory' during up-to-date check.
>
> >java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: P:\React Native\JDream\node_modules\react-native-linear-gradient\android\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\debug

Answer (score 16):

If you are using android 
just follow these steps:

1. `cd android`
2. `gradlew clean`
3. `cd ..`
4. `react-native run-android`

Comment: Thank you, your answer did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

have you tried 'sudo'

```
npm start
sudo react-native run-android
```

Comment: This solution sometimes stuck's  at 99% during app:install debug task